# Check if a specific hidden div exists and if not create one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to check if a specific hidden div exists and if not create one.

I do:

```
function myFunction(somestring) {

   var myHiddenDiv = jQuery('<div id="js_method" style="display:none">'); 
   ...
   myHiddenDiv.append(somestring);

}
```

The problem is this seems to create a new hidden div every time the function is called on the same page.

the hidden div just seems scoped to the function, whereas I want it scoped to the page.

Any tips.

tips please
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use length property:-

```
function myFunction(somestring) {
var myHiddenDiv;
if($("#js_method").length == 0){
   myHiddenDiv = jQuery('<div id="js_method" style="display:none">'); 
   $("body").append(myHiddenDiv);
}else{
    myHiddenDiv = $("#js_method");
}
   ...
   myHiddenDiv.append(somestring);

}
```

Comment: Won't work. If I do:      if (jQuery("#js_method").length === 0) {

jQuery('<div id="js_method" style="display:none">');
}   
jQuery("#js_method").length  The length is zero

Comment: It will be remain zero first time but when you create the div then it will not. You need to append the div to the dom also.

Comment: Appending to the Dom that's the part I am missing. Can you update solution as this was crux of question. How to maintain the div across invocations of the function?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check by ID?

```
if (jQuery("#js_method").length == 0) {
    var myHiddenDiv = jQuery('<div id="js_method" style="display:none">'); 
    ...
    myHiddenDiv.append(somestring);
}
```